# Does C++ compiler generate code for every template class instance with the same set of template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Lest consider well-known compile time recursive fibonacci calculation. In this particular case how many times `fibonacci<1>` (or `fibonacci<20>` doesn't matter) was  instantiated? Was it exactly once? If yes, compiler does dynamic programming algorithm for us :)

```
    template<int n>
    struct fibonacci
    {
        static const uint64_t value = fibonacci<n - 1>::value + fibonacci<n - 2>::value;
    };

    template<>
    struct fibonacci<0>
    {
        static const  uint64_t value = 0;
    };

    template<>
    struct fibonacci<1>
    {
        static const uint64_t value = 1;
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << fibonacci<80>::value;
    }
```

Lets consider another example.

```
    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> v1;
        std::vector<int> v2;
    }
```

Does C++ compiler generate separate code code for both instances of `vector<int>`?
What if similar instances of `vector<int>` was in different translation units?

Comment: that comparison (fibonacci vs vector<int>) isnt very meaningful, because to get the result of `fibonacci<80>` at runtime, in principle there need not be any function (at runtime)

Comment: Without some serious and aggressive caching strategies, there's no way modern C++ compilers can be reasonably fast, given that a simple "hello world" code might end up being expanded to a 40K lines of code by the preprocessor, so my bet is Yes

Comment: @WhiZTiM is preprocessor related to template code generation? Yes is answer on 2nd question?

Comment: How compiler handle that code depends on the compiler. If you want to see what gcc or clang creates of of your `fibonacci` you should take a look at the created assembly code. gcc 7 will evaluate the code at compile time and store the result as precompiled information. A nice online tool is [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/). For `vector<int>` the compiler might create the same code for each compilation unit, but will only use one at linking.

Comment: @t.niese thanks. I know this tool. I rephrase question. Will compiler blindly generate full recursion tree or cache calculated values?

Comment: @Viktor No, that was a general note, and an assumption you shouldn't bank on. However, even as stupid as I am, when writing a C++ compiler (not feasible), I will cache the *specializations* created by *template instatiations*, If I recall correctly, I've seen a post here w.r.t to wrongly generated *class-template specialization*, and this was as a result of a bug in GCC's (I think) template caching strategy

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not mandate one or the other. As long as the finished program behaves as specified, a compiler may do anything, see the so-called "as-if" rule (§1.9-1). A good compiler will not generate unnecessary code, so I would expect it to optimize the fibonacci example to a constant, and the vector example to one implementation of the vector functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on something called "implicit instantiation" here. Explicit template instantiation would be

```
template class fibonacci<0>;
template class fibonacci<1>;
template class fibonacci<2>;
// etc
```

Now, the possibility of explicit template instantiation allows you to turn off implicit instantiation:

```
extern template class fibonacci<0>;
extern template class fibonacci<1>;
extern template class fibonacci<2>;
// etc
```

Why is this relevant? It means the compiler already has a fairly refined mechanism to deal with template instantiations. For implicit instantiation to work, a compiler must necessarily be able to check on the instantiation status, so it won't implicitly instantiate templates that have been explicitly instantiated.

So, it follows that there is an "what's the instantiation status?" check. And that may return "already implicitly instantiated". It would be a pessimization to re-instantiate the template in that case!

Answer (score 0):

> In this particular case how many times fibonacci<1> (or fibonacci<20> doesn't matter) was instantiated?

Zero objects and only a static (const!) value.

With

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
```

are instantiated two objects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Lets consider I have two template functions or classes with same parameters. Will linker get rid of redundancy?

Comment: @Viktor - for functions you should propose an example but for your `fibonacci` class, yes: it's the meaning of `static` for members. Given a template parameter, say `1`, you can use `fibonacci<1>::value` a zillion of times and there is only a static `value` variable (better: constant). Different if `value` isn't `static`: you have to create a zillion of instances of `fibonacci<1>` and use they (something like `fibonacci<1> f1; f1.value`).